# Doxygen doesn't work with duplicate file names

Tags: doxygen

In my php app there are some duplicate file names in different directories. If I write

```
* @file /full/path/to/file.php
```

every file is found and parsed.

But if I only write the relative path only the last found file seems to be parsed.

I'm writing a portable app, so I cannot work with full paths.

Is there a way to get it working?

UPDATE: I have found a workaround by defining aliases in the config for the different dirs.

But is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to specify the complete path, [just enough to make it unique](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdfile). For example:

In `/path/to/project/featureA/file.php` use `@file featureA/file.php`.

In `/path/to/project/featureB/file.php` use `@file featureB/file.php`.